# How to create a shortcut of file/folder?

Tags: command-line, bash, 22.04

I have successfully created shortcuts for files and folders using the following command:

```
ln -s folder_path destination_link_path
```

**For files:**

```
ln -s /home/user/doc.txt /home/user/Desktop/doc.lnk
```

**For Folders:**

```
ln -s /media/user/Disk1/Data /home/user/Desktop
```

However, I am also interested to know if there is an alternative method to create shortcuts using the Ubuntu UI. If anyone knows of such an approach, please share your insights.

**Edit:**
I have found the solution. To enable the "Create Link" option in Nautilus (Ubuntu File Manager), follow these steps:

1. Click on the three-line bars in the upper right corner to open the
   preferences menu.
2. In the preferences menu, navigate to "Optional Context Menu
   Actions."
3. Toggle on the option labeled "Create Link."

After completing these steps, whenever you right-click on a folder in Nautilus, you will see the "Create Link" option available in the context menu.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu 22.04 ? Right click and "Create a link" ?

Comment: Thanks, got it. It wasn't visible at first. I had to turn it on in preferences.